Specify number of shards for auto-created index
I am working on my first OpenSearch project. We have a product that produces static websites for about 500 customers. Most customers have 10-50 of these rarely-updated static sites and they typically add another 1-3 sites per year. Each website has an ID, and that ID is used as the index name on OpenSearch. When a site is published, the system crawls the new site and uploads search documents, one per webpage, to an OpenSearch instance. We do not explicitly create the index separately but use OpenSearch's behavior of creating an index automatically when it receives a search document for an index that does not yet exist.
However, the indexes are created with 5 primary shards and 5 replicas. I am running up against the instance's maximum number of shards. So I want it to create 1 primary shard and 1 replica if it needs to create a new index. Is there a way to specify that in the search document JSON, or with query string parameters on the POST URL, or some other way? I am trying to avoid re-engineering (and re-scheduling, re-reviewing, re-testing, etc.) the system to check for and create indexes explicitly.
I have been combing the OpenSearch documentation and I can see how to set the number of shards when I explicitly create an index separately, but not automatically. Is there a way?
I am hoping to avoid re-engineering it to manually check for and create indexes but I guess that would be my next step if I can't add in a property or parameter to specify number of shards if a document is uploaded for a non-existent index.
At this point, when the system uploads a document that is for an index that doesn't yet exist, the index is not successfully created because creating 10 shards would exceed the server's maximum shards setting (currently 2000, and I already have 1998). We have been advised against setting the server's max number of shards to a high enough number to accommodate all the sites with 10 shards each (we would need to raise it to something like 40000).
